# How to access to an element in an array?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I've tried to access to an element in a array but I keep getting errors.
Here's my declaration of my array :
`String[] tTest = ["A", "B", "C"]`

I've tried with the index :`print tTest[0]` and with the function getAt : `print tTest.getAt(0)` but it didn't worked.
Can someone help me ?
Thx.

Comment: Which complete and exact error did you get?

Comment: "Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getAt java.lang.Object[]" and "unclassified method java.lang.String[] getAt java.lang.Integer"

Comment: I've found my error... it wasn't my access to the element but my print of that element... Thank you @JBNizet

Answer (score 0):

For example:

- `println tTest[0]` - to print a particular element (*A*),
- `int nn = tTest.size()` - to get the size of the array (*3*).

`println tTest.getAt(2)` also worked. I used Groovy web console at http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/